# No match function for open cv calcHist

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm using OpenCV in the iOS app. I try to calculate histogram, but once I put all parameters into the function, it gives no match function error.

Following is my code:

```
  cv::Mat temp2;
  cv::MatND output_his;
  const int channels[] = { 1 };
  const int histSize[] = { 256 };
  const float hranges[] = { 0, 256 };
  
  // cv::calcHist(<#const Mat *images#>, <#int nimages#>, <#const int *channels#>, <#InputArray mask#>, <#OutputArray hist#>, <#int dims#>, <#const int *histSize#>, <#const float **ranges#>)

  cv::calcHist(temp2, 1, channels, cv::Mat(), output_his, 2, histSize, hranges);
```

Can you help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I use this in my projects. Maybe this code will help :).

```
inline cv::Mat calcHist(cv::Mat grayscaleImage)
{
    const int bins          = 256;
    const int histSize[]    = { bins };
    const float range[]     = { 0.f, 256.f };
    const float* ranges[]   = { range };
    const int channels[]    = { 0 };

    cv::Mat hist;
    cv::calcHist(&grayscaleImage, 1, channels, cv::Mat(), hist, 1, histSize, ranges);

    return hist;
}
```